# Hibernate criteria specific query

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have such entity:

```
public class LogEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer id;
    private Date changeTime;
    private Set<Integer> changes; 

    //getters and setters

}
```

And its mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.myproject.dao.LogEntity" table="LOG">
    <id name="id" column="ID" type="integer">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="changeTime" column="CHANGE_TIME" type="timestamp"/>
    <set name="changes" table="LOG_CHANGES" lazy="false" cascade="all" order-by="CHANGE_ID">
        <key column="ID"/>
        <element column="CHANGE_ID" type="integer"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

The problem is how to check that `Set<Integer> changes` contains given parameter using hibernate criteria. I can't `createAlias()` for this and also try to use `sqlRestriction()` but get something ugly.

I am pretty sure that there is some easy way but I just cant see it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you show what you have tried and the issue you are facing in that?

Comment: I try to do it like this: `criteria.createAlias("changes", "c").add(Restrictions.eq("c.CHANGE_ID", param));` and get org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal syntax near collection: CHANGE_ID. Than I try to use sqlRestriction: criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("select * from LOG_CHANGES c where c.CHANGE_ID like ?", param, IntegerType.INSTANCE));

Comment: whatever you are doing is completely wrong, better you go through hibernate documentation to understand how to write Criteria queries.